# Recover Index File + Overwrite or Hacked by SomeOne + Linux Server

Tags: linux, web-services, security

Some body overwrites my index file of every folder at linux server. Is it possible to recover all the files from server to make website in running state.

Comment: Is there anything through which we can avoid such type of Hacking activities..

Answer (score 1):

No, recover them from your backups.

Comment: Sorry Friend, Issue is that previous data belongs to the PHP and now new one is of ROR. But i dnt have any backup, that why this issue arises. Please suggest me other than Backup.